# sum of digits in sql

Tags: sql, sum

The database scheme consists of four tables:

```
Product(maker, model, type)    
PC(code, model, speed, ram, hd, cd, price)    
Laptop(code, model, speed, ram, hd, screen, price)    
Printer(code, model, color, type, price)
```

- The Product table contains data on the maker, model number, and type of product ('PC', 'Laptop', or 'Printer'). It is assumed that model numbers in the Product table are unique for all makers and product types.
- Each personal computer in the PC table is unambiguously identified by a unique code, and is additionally characterized by its model (foreign key referring to the Product table), processor speed (in MHz) – speed field, RAM capacity (in Mb) - ram, hard disk drive capacity (in Gb) – hd, CD-ROM speed (e.g, '4x') - cd, and its price.
- The Laptop table is similar to the PC table, except that instead of the CD-ROM speed, it contains the screen size (in inches) – screen.
- For each printer model in the Printer table, its output type (‘y’ for color and ‘n’ for monochrome) – color field, printing technology ('Laser', 'Jet', or 'Matrix') – type, and price are specified.

Calculate the sum of digits in each model's ID (model column) from Product table.
Result set: model, sum of digits

Please tell me how to solve it. I am of intermediate sql skill and cant solve this.

Comment: We fix code you've written. We're not here to write it for you.

Comment: `n % 10 + n / 10 % 10 + n / 100 % 10 ...` `%` is the modulus/remainder operation which might be a function like `mod()` on your platform. This is really a math problem more than a "SQL" problem. If your ID is a string you'll have to convert to int. If it's longer than 9 characters you should use a "bigint" or break it into pieces.

Comment: @MarcB SO does much more than "fix code you've written." This is not a debugging service. We *answer questions* by providing information and sharing knowledge. *Some* narrowly scoped questions asking for code are fine. But however you describe it, please don't foster the notion that we're here to fix other people's code; that's no better than just writing code for people.

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: well can someone tell me where to begin? what should i do.

Comment: @jpmc26: but we also have the right to expect people to TRY and solve the problem first. We're also NOT a code writing service.

Comment: @mitzy I already gave you an answer. You need more specific information like which database platform you use and a sample of the id's you're working with. And considering that about 95% of your question is irrelevant it's clear that this is homework and that you haven't really tried anything yet.

Comment: @MarcB I'm aware, and I said all that. My point is you still completely misrepresented what kind of content is appropriate for SO, and in a way that *encourages* bad questions. If you're going to comment on the quality of a question to a new user, *do it right*.

Comment: @jpmc26: trust me, there's a lot of blatant "I'm lazy, do my job for me" stuff on this site. I spend more time downvoting/close voting than I do answering these days. So yeah, I get terse.

Comment: I also agree with @MarcB here. This kind of question is clearly an assignment where the OP couldn't solve and instead of trying to solve it he just dumped it here in hope someone will answer for him. I also think that SO should have a specific close vote to homework/assignments question.

Comment: i like the functions. But can you explain the sum of digits function with clause

Comment: also im using sql server.

Comment: i dont understand the logic of the function

Answer (score 2):

OK, with the help of two functions, we can parse your model numbers into digits and then get the sum of digits.

```
Select [dbo].[udf-Stat-Sum-of-Digits](12345)     -- Returns 15
Select [dbo].[dbo].[udf-Str-Numbers]('AF567-56') -- Returns 56756
```

The good news is that we can combine these as illustrated below

```
Declare @Table table (model varchar(50))
Insert into @Table values
('AF567-56'),
('25-a-467'),
('11156 25')

Select Model
      ,Digits = [dbo].[udf-Str-Numbers](Model)
      ,SumOfDigits = [dbo].[udf-Stat-Sum-of-Digits]([dbo].[udf-Str-Numbers](Model))
 From  @Table
```

Returns

```
Model       Digits  SumOfDigits
AF567-56    56756   29
25-a-467    25467   24
11156 25    1115625 21
```

The two UDFs

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[udf-Stat-Sum-of-Digits](@Val int)
Returns Int
As
Begin

Declare @RetVal as int

;with i AS (
    Select @Val / 10 n, @Val % 10 d
    Union ALL
    Select n / 10, n % 10
    From i
    Where n > 0
)
Select @RetVal = SUM(d) FROM i;

Return @RetVal

END
```

The second Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Numbers](@String varchar(250))
Returns Varchar(250)
As
Begin
    Declare @RetVal varchar(250) = @String
    ;with cteChar as (Select Cnt=1,Str=Char(1) Union All Select Cnt=B.Cnt+1,Str=Char(B.Cnt+1) From cteChar as B Where B.Cnt <= 255)
    Select @RetVal = Replace(@RetVal,Str,'') From cteChar where str not like '[0-9]' Option (maxrecursion 256)
    Return case when IsNull(@RetVal,'')='' then @String else @RetVal end
END
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution passes the check

```
SELECT model, 
    1 * (DATALENGTH(model) - DATALENGTH(REPLACE(model, '1', ''))) +
    2 * (DATALENGTH(model) - DATALENGTH(REPLACE(model, '2', ''))) +
    3 * (DATALENGTH(model) - DATALENGTH(REPLACE(model, '3', ''))) +
    4 * (DATALENGTH(model) - DATALENGTH(REPLACE(model, '4', ''))) +
    5 * (DATALENGTH(model) - DATALENGTH(REPLACE(model, '5', ''))) +
    6 * (DATALENGTH(model) - DATALENGTH(REPLACE(model, '6', ''))) +
    7 * (DATALENGTH(model) - DATALENGTH(REPLACE(model, '7', ''))) +
    8 * (DATALENGTH(model) - DATALENGTH(REPLACE(model, '8', ''))) +
    9 * (DATALENGTH(model) - DATALENGTH(REPLACE(model, '9', ''))) AS 'qty'
FROM product
```

Answer (score -1):

It's quite interesting, that my solution with LEN method hasn't passes the check.
The only difference is the method.

According to documentation the main difference between LEN and DATALENGTH is that DATALENGTH counts bytes, LEN counts symbols.

So it looks like that LEN method is better for the task.
But stiil we can pass chech only with DATALENGTH .

```
SELECT 
    model, 
    1 * (len(model) - len(replace(model,'1',''))) +
    2 * (len(model) - len(replace(model,'2',''))) +
    3 * (len(model) - len(replace(model,'3',''))) +
    4 * (len(model) - len(replace(model,'4',''))) +
    5 * (len(model) - len(replace(model,'5',''))) +
    6 * (len(model) - len(replace(model,'6',''))) +
    7 * (len(model) - len(replace(model,'7',''))) +
    8 * (len(model) - len(replace(model,'8',''))) +
    9 * (len(model) - len(replace(model,'9','')))  AS 'sum_fig'
FROM product
```