# TSQL - Adding each digit in a variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there an easy way to add each digit in an integer variable or do I have loop it per digit. Let's say that variable have a series of number:

```
|Digit_tbl| 690644694
```

Result:

```
|Digit_tbl| 48
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sum of digits in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38665486/sum-of-digits-in-sql)

Comment: Is this a varchar column or an integer?

Comment: this is not a column, it is an int variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is using a recursive cte:

```
declare @num int = 690644694;


with cte as (
    select @num as num, @num % 10 as digit 
    union all
    select num / 10, num / 10 % 10
    from cte
    where num > 0
)

SELECT SUM(digit)
FROM cte
```

Result: `48`

Another option, which should probably have better performance (not that it can be measured for a single int) is to use a powers of ten tally cte:

```
declare @num int = 690644694;

With Tally as
(
    SELECT TOP 10 POWER(10, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @@SPID))-1) As n
    FROM sys.objects
)

SELECT SUM(@num / n % 10)
FROM Tally
WHERE n <= @num
```

(the maximum value of `int` in sql server has 10 digits - hence the `top 10` - values in the tally cte are 1, 10, 100, .... 1000000000)

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Comment: Why does it is ' % 10 ' not in '% 9 '

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this question. `% 10` will give the singles digit. `% 9` will give wrong results if the singles digit is `0` - it will give `1`.

Answer (score 2):

Integer division and modulo operator could be used to extract each digit from an integer:

```
SELECT number, SUM(number / divisor % 10) AS digitsum
FROM (VALUES
    (690644694),
    (2147483647)
) AS t(number)
INNER JOIN (VALUES
    (1),
    (10),
    (100),
    (1000),
    (10000),
    (100000),
    (1000000),
    (10000000),
    (100000000),
    (1000000000)
) AS x(divisor) ON divisor <= number
GROUP BY number
```

Comment: This would be a great solution if the value was a string, but it's an int. However, you did inspire me to find a tally based solution, so you did help at least one person today with this answer :-)

Comment: @zohar yes OP mentioned int after I posted the answer. Updated neverheless.